# How to attach image in vCard (vcf file) using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, vcf-vcard

In my project I need to create and send a vCard (vcf file) that must include an image too. I did everything right except I can not add image to the vCard. I have shared my code below.

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

  NSError *error;
  NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vCard.vcf"];
  [[self vCardRepresentation] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

  UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]] applicationActivities:nil];
  activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
  [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{

}];
}

- (NSString *)vCardRepresentation
{
   NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Rokon"], 1.0);

  [mutableArray addObject:@"BEGIN:VCARD"];
  [mutableArray addObject:@"VERSION:3.0"];
  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FN:%@", @"Rokon"]];
  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEL:%@",@"+8801811536248"]];
  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHOTO;BASE64:%@",[imageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0]]];
  [mutableArray addObject:@"END:VCARD"];

  return [mutableArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)shareContact{
        [self emptySandbox];
        NSString *contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[Person sharedInstance].firstName, [Person sharedInstance].lastName];
        NSError *error;
        NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.vcf", contactName]];
        [[self vCardRepresentation] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[contactName, [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]] applicationActivities:nil];

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
        [activityVC setValue:contactName forKey:@"subject"];

        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
 }


- (NSString *)vCardRepresentation
  {
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([Person sharedInstance].profileImage, 1.0);

[mutableArray addObject:@"BEGIN:VCARD"];
[mutableArray addObject:@"VERSION:3.0"];

[mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FN:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [Person sharedInstance].firstName, [Person sharedInstance].lastName]]];
[mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEL:%@",[Person sharedInstance].phone]];
[mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email:%@", [Person sharedInstance].email]];
[mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHOTO;BASE64;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:%@",[imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]]];
[mutableArray addObject:@"END:VCARD"];
return [mutableArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}

-(void)emptySandbox
{
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *files = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

while (files.count > 0) {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *directoryContents = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
    if (error == nil) {
        for (NSString *path in directoryContents) {
            NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
            BOOL removeSuccess = [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
            files = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
            if (!removeSuccess) {
                // Error
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Error
    }
 }
}
```